# Как сделать запрет перехода к родительской активити

Tags: java, android

подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть mainactivity на котором пользователь выбирает дату. После нажатия ок переходит на вторую активити и если нажать стрелку назад то переходит назад и выбирает новую дату. Здесь все нормально.
Необходимо чтобы если пользователь уже выбирал дату, то при запуске приложения открывалась сразу вторая активити. Реализовал это с помощью обычного флага

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    shp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    ed = shp.edit();
    Boolean a = shp.getBoolean("isVisited", false);

    if(a){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data", dateSt);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Но проблема в том, что нужно запретить переход назад на mainactivity в случае если повторно открывается приложение. Подскажите как поступить? Если просто заблокировать кнопку назад, то она будет заблокирована всегда, а нужно именно после первичного старта приложения.

Comment: Делать finish() в if

Comment: Можно реализовать также с помощью флага, но этот вариант будет не очень. Т.е. при запуске приложения спрашивать и сразу запускать интент на 2ую активити.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Спасибо, достаточно просто и логично для меня, как для новичка

Comment: @MakoStorm думал сразу об этом, но оказалось слишком проблемным для меня из-за того, что в разных случаях разное поведение необходимо

Comment: если не нужен переход обратно, то при вызове второй активити нужно [очищать стек переходов](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack) (back stack)

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо